# Velocity Engine without init()

Tags: java, velocity

I would like to know how Velocity Template works without initializaion.

**There is no Initialization : like below**

```
     Velocity.init();            
         OR
     VelocityEngine velocity = new VelocityEngine();
     velocity.init();
```

**Code which runs without init():**

```
System.out.println("Hello World from Java Source");     
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put( "name", new String("Velocity") );

Template template = Velocity.getTemplate("default-template.vm");        
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
template.merge( context, sw );
System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

**Output :**

```
Hello World from Java Source
Hello World from Velocity Template
```

Comment: Did you find out the answer to this by any chance? I'm puzzled by the same scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the getTemplate method performs an initialization check and does the init if Velocity is not yet initialized.

From Velocity 1.7 Source:

```
 public Template getTemplate(String name, String  encoding)
            throws ResourceNotFoundException, ParseErrorException
        {
            requireInitialization();

            return (Template)
                    resourceManager.getResource(name,
                        ResourceManager.RESOURCE_TEMPLATE, encoding);
        }



 private void requireInitialization()
    {
        if (!initialized)
        {
            try
            {
                init();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                getLog().error("Could not auto-initialize Velocity", e);
                throw new RuntimeException("Velocity could not be initialized!", e);
            }
        }
    }
```